# Is there a version of Taylor's theorem with integral remainder which is valid if the function is only differentiable in a weak sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, taylor-expansion, weak-derivatives

Short question: Is there a version of Taylor's theorem with integral remainder which is valid if the function ($\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$) is only differentiable in a [weak sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative#Definition)? Or at least if the function is ordinary differentiable except for the derivative occurring in the integral remainder?